# How does the following functional implementation of a deque support extraction in amortised constant-time?

Tags: haskell, data-structures, functional-programming, deque, amortized-analysis

In [Data.List](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/Data.OldList.html#emptySB) module, the following data structure is used

```
{- We store a front list, a rear list, and the length of the queue.  Because we
only snoc onto the queue and never uncons, we know it's time to rotate when the
length of the queue plus 1 is a power of 2. Note that we rely on the value of
the length field only for performance.  In the unlikely event of overflow, the
performance will suffer but the semantics will remain correct.  -}

data SnocBuilder a = SnocBuilder {-# UNPACK #-} !Word [a] [a]

{- Smart constructor that rotates the builder when lp is one minus a power of
2. Does not rotate very small builders because doing so is not worth the
trouble. The lp < 255 test goes first because the power-of-2 test gives awful
branch prediction for very small n (there are 5 powers of 2 between 1 and
16). Putting the well-predicted lp < 255 test first avoids branching on the
power-of-2 test until powers of 2 have become sufficiently rare to be predicted
well. -}

{-# INLINE sb #-}
sb :: Word -> [a] -> [a] -> SnocBuilder a
sb lp f r
  | lp < 255 || (lp .&. (lp + 1)) /= 0 = SnocBuilder lp f r
  | otherwise                          = SnocBuilder lp (f ++ reverse r) []

-- The empty builder

emptySB :: SnocBuilder a
emptySB = SnocBuilder 0 [] []

-- Add an element to the end of a queue.

snocSB :: SnocBuilder a -> a -> SnocBuilder a
snocSB (SnocBuilder lp f r) x = sb (lp + 1) f (x:r)

-- Convert a builder to a list

toListSB :: SnocBuilder a -> [a]
toListSB (SnocBuilder _ f r) = f ++ reverse r
```

A comment above the snippet mentions goes as follows:

> The queue guarantees (amortized) O(1) `snoc` and O(1) `uncons`,
>   meaning that we can think of `toListSB` as an O(1) conversion to a
>   list-like structure a constant factor slower than normal lists--we pay
>   the O(n) cost incrementally as we consume the list.

I do not understand why `toListSB` is working in O(1) amortised. Isn't the length of the right list increasing larger and larger between consecutive powers of 2?

Comment: If it increases larger and larger, that means reversing (which would be costly to do every time) is becoming rarer and rarer.

Comment: @Bergi but, I would have to reverse the right list every time I want to `toListSB`

Comment: Yes, `toListSB` is not `O(1)`, it's `O(n)`. But calling `snocSB` n times is only `O(n)` not `O(n²)`

Comment: @Bergi but the comment states, *we can think of toListSB as an O(1) conversion*. Are they wrong, here?

Comment: Ah, I didn't pay attention. Yeah, in Haskell everything is `O(0)` until it gets consumed :-) Converting to and consuming the list takes `O(n)` together.

Comment: So the cost is O(N) every N calls so we pay 1/N O(N) each call.

Answer (score 1):

If current length of list is `N=2^M`, then there were M operations of doubling. The first doubling takes 1 time unit, the second 0 2 time units, the third - 4 and so on. But it is known (geometric progression sum formula) that

```
1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + ...+2^M = 2^(M+1) - 1 = O(N)
```

So amortized cost per one operation is `O(N)/N = O(1)`

Comment: This seems to be the analysis of `snocSB`, I was looking for the time complexity of `toListSB`

Comment: `toListSB` is certainly O(n).  The comment you quoted explains that n `snocSB` operations followed by a `toListSB` as a whole requires O(n) work.  

It's curious that the comments talk about an uncons operation but the [code](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/src/Data-OldList.html) doesn't have one.